# Adding MIME type to website instead of IIS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mime-types, offline-caching

I'm getting a weird invalidstateerror DOM exception error 11 when I call swapCache():

```
Error: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
at DOMApplicationCache.<anonymous>
```

The cache seems to work as expected (even with the DOM error, which I don't understand).  This appears to be a solution...

[Possible Fix for Offline App Cache INVALIDSTATEERR](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/possible-fix-for-offline-app-cache-invalid_state_err)

...but I have NO IDEA how to set the MIME types client side.  Googling isn't helping me, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: In what browser/version does this error occur?

Comment: Chrome v25, latest update.